# OSX password issue with special chars in recovery mode

Tags: macbook-pro

I had an issue with my MacBook (latest version) and I tried restarting in recovery mode (cmd+r).
The issue is that my password contains a special character (umbreakable space) for security reasons  with an alt+Space combination.
However the recovery mode does not consider the alt key and the default space is typed instead, therefore the password is incorrect.

Now I’m stuck in recovery mode when booting anyhow with the black screen and a grey lock and I don’t know how to get out of there.

Note that my hard disk is encrypted if that has any impact.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you go in to terminal and type resetpassword?  That should take you to a dialog to reset your password.  You have to select your disk and your user account along the way...

Warning:  Changing your password like this might break your keychain.